# Control text size by cell content in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column interval;

The cells of this interval will receive either a 0 or a 1 (zero or one);

I want the text size of the "zero cells" to be 9;

And the text size of the "one cells" to be 10.

I have tried to write a custom function using the script tool, but I was unsuccessful so far.

The function script I am trying to use:

```
function FONTSIZE(cell,size)
 {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(cell);
  cell.setFontSize(size);
 }
```

And the plan was to use an if function together:

```
IF(A1 = 1; FONTSIZE(A1,10); FONTSIZE(A1,9))
```

Should I be trying to use a function? Is this the right way?

Can a function change the text format of its cell at all?

Could someone please help me?

Comment: In your formula of `IF(A1 = 1; FONTSIZE(A1,10); FONTSIZE(A1,9))`, the value is used as the 1st argument of `FONTSIZE`. In this case, `cell` of the GAS function `FONTSIZE(cell,size)` is the string. By this, I think that an error occurs at `cell.setFontSize(size)`. And, unfortunately, `setFontSize` cannot be used with the custom function. So even when `sheet.getRange(cell).setFontSize(size)` where `cell` is `"A1" is used, an error occurs. Under this situation, can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: Well, I found this sheet while on the web:
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fSHb5bG9805_SM6BTFjyl2NDZdDd9H2sBGYf4NXqcDA/edit#gid=359784640

... and noticed that the empty dots and the filled dots are different sizes, and was wondering if I could automate a way to change the font size so they appear to be about the same size when empty and filled.

And then suddenly when I realize, I was trying to write my own custom functions and asking help on stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actually I am still looking for a solution. Thanks for the help so far.